# SQL Server query performance mystery

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-performance

I've had far too many meetings today, but I think I still have my brainware in place.
In my effort to improve the performance of some query I came across the following mystery (table names and fields paraphrased):

```
SELECT X.ADId FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT A.ADId
    FROM P WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN A WITH (NOLOCK) ON (P.ID = A.PId)
    INNER JOIN dbo.fn_A(16) AS VD ON (VD.DId = A.ADId)
    LEFT JOIN DPR ON (LDID = A.ADId)
    WHERE ((A.ADId = 1) OR ((HDId IS NOT NULL) AND (HDId = 1))) AND
           (P.PS NOT IN(5,7)) AND (A.ASP IN (2, 3))
) X
WHERE (dbo.fn_B(X.ADId, 16) = 1)
```

As you will see, the contents of the inner query are mostly irrelevant.
The whole point initially was that I wanted to avoid getting fn_B() called on every record cause they contained duplicate values for ADId, so I did a SELECT DISTINCT internally then filter the distinct records.
Sounds reasonable right?

Here starts the mystery...

The inner query returns NO RECORDS (for the specified parameters).
If I comment out the "WHERE fn_B() = 1" then the query runs in zero time (and returns no results).
If I put it back on, then the query takes 6-10 seconds, again returning no results.

This seems to beat common sense, or at least MY common SQL sense :-)
If the inner query returns no data, then the outer conditions should never get evaluated right?

Of course I took the time to check the actual execution plans, saved them and compared them very carefully. They are 99% identical, with nothing unusual to notice, or so I think.

I fooled around with some CTEs to get the query results in the first CTE, and then pass it to a second CTE that had some conditions guaranteed to filter no records, then evaluate the fn_B() call outside all CTEs, but the behavior was exactly the same.

Also other variations, like using the old query (that might call fn_B() multiple times with the same value) had the same behavior. If I remove the condition then I get no records in zero time. If I put it back, then no records in 10 seconds.

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks for your time :-)

PS1: I tried to reproduce the situation on tempdb using a simple query but I couldn't make it happen. It only happens on my actual tables.
PS2: This query is called inside another function so putting the results in a temporary table and then further filtering them is also out of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a note, the optimizer does not read a query the same way you do. Even when you think that a certain order should take place, or that short-circuiting might make the most sense, the optimizer still might evaluate CTEs / subqueries in an order you might not expect. A workaround you might try is selecting the first query into a #temp table and then running the function filter on the #temp table. This should force the order of evaluation even if it is completely unintuitive and much less elegant.

**EDIT**

Also, while it may perform slower, I am curious what happens if you run the query without the NOLOCK, or in RCSI instead. Different locking semantics may be tripping up the optimizer.

Comment: I think most people are already aware that the optimizer rearranges things in strange ways. BUT sometimes queries are written in such a way so that the programmer is in charge of what happens. If I do two SELECT DISCTINCTs then JOIN them, I am roughly sure what will happen. Anyway, I am going to try out today some invocations that where the inner query actually brings data, or where I replace fn_B() with a dummy function, just to see how the behavior changes.

Comment: You would think so, but there are plenty of exceptions. The optimizer is not perfect. Did you read Hugo's blog post and bug report just today? https://sqlblog.org/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/2012/05/04/the-curious-case-of-the-optimizer-that-doesn-t.aspx I've seen several cases where the only way to enforce the behavior I expected from the optimizer was to break the query into separate queries. It's just an idea you can try, as I suggested above.

Comment: Extra info. I run the inner query with params that return 6 rows. Zero time. Add the WHERE ==> 30 sec. I made 6 explicit calls to fn(B) with these IDs, total 0 sec. I put the whole thing in the profiler and here what gives... SQL Server begins an avalanche of Table Scans, on the SAME 5 tables, over and over and over again (approx. 100.000 entries in the profiler log) and then executes the query. All these tables appear inside fn_B(), which never gets called in the original example. Removing NOLOCK made no differecnce. So I am starting to figure that something is confusing SQL server here.

Comment: I don't doubt that I/we will find a way around it eventually. My point is that this appears like highly abnormal behavior, so I personally need to understand why it is happening.

Answer (score 0):

We submitted the issue to Microsoft support for SQL Server R2 (I must comment on their amazing response times and overall service procedures). We gave them a copy of our DB that reproduces the issue, and our workaround, they reproduced it themselves and after a couple of days here is the answer we got back:

> I have analyzed both execution plans and would kindly ask if the
>   workaround would be acceptable to use in production? The main reason
>   behind it, is that a function does not have, as indexes have,
>   statistics. And this lack of data makes the optimizer choose sometimes
>   a not so good execution plan. If you already found a workaround it is
>   best to implement this. The index changes we tried did not improve the
>   execution.

This is quite a diplomatic way to say "yeah, the optimizer messes things up with your query, so please use the workaround". If you wanna call it a bug, call it a bug, it doesn't matter.

Just for the record, the workaround was to put the call to fn_B() in the SELECT list of a query one level above the SELECT DISTINCT, then filter its result on the WHERE condition. Kind of weird, but it does the trick.